# Javascript get value of DIV value without HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am assigning the div with values "AMD", "APPLE".

```
<div id="company"></div>
```

However, when i call **outputStock()** my alert value shows **HTML tags.** How can i get the current **String** value i assigned?

```
<script>
    var company = ["AMD", "APPLE"];
    company.forEach(function(i) {
        document.getElementById("company").innerHTML+= "<p>" + i + "</p>";
    });
</script>
<script>
    function outputStock() {
        var stockname = document.getElementById("company").innerHTML;
        alert(stockname);
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE*:** when I output the alert() i get

```
<p>AMD</p><br><hr><p>APPLE</p><br><hr>
```

how can i get rid of html tags in alert And just get the strings?
Something like this?

```
document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
```

Comment: A `<div>` element does not have a `.value`? To get the value you assigned, you should use the same property: `.innerHTML`.

Comment: by value you mean the company name you assigned?

Comment: yes the name "AAPL"

Comment: edit: If you use innerHtml like that will it override the event handlers, use appendTo

Comment: How can i get the output without html tags in an alert()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divs content is innerHTML not value if you change that it will return AMD and APPLE.

```js
var company = ["AMD", "APPLE"];
company.forEach(function(i) {
document.getElementById("company").innerHTML+= "<p>" + i + "</p>";
});



var name = document.getElementById("company").innerHTML
var noTags = name.replace('<p>' , ' ').replace('</p>' , ' ').replace('<p>' , ' ').replace('</p>' , ' ')
alert(noTags)
```

```html
<div id="company"></div>
```

Comment: How can i get the output without html tags in an alert()?

Comment: That edit will strip the paragraph tags but it isn't a good way to do it. Can you not add the paragraph tags?

Comment: I need the paragraph tags

Comment: Then just strip them out with replace I updated the example to return an alert with just the text AMD and APPLE

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var company = ["AMD", "APPLE"];
    company.forEach(function(i) {
        document.getElementById("company").innerHTML += "<p>" + i + "</p><br />" + "<hr>";
     });
</script>      
<script>
     function outputStock() {
         var name = document.getElementById("company").innerHTML;
         alert(name);
     } 
</script>
```

> Div tag doesn't have any attribute such as value. To retrieve any value from div tag you must use .innerHTML